# using inplace-editor with ajax and storing in XMl file in server

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts, inplace-editing

I want to use inplace editor in my jsp get the code from xml file after it gets edited again should be saved in xml file through ajax. I am using struts 1 framework.

Please help me out as i am using this to create a help manual which can be allowed to edit i dont want to create some more tables and fill in all details in my table every time. So i thought to go with xml file.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the file and then rebooting your computer. go to cmd-gos and press enter thrice. a pop up screen should appear and this is when you begin to mash your keyboard. then reboot the computer again, empty the trash, defrag and repeat the process. if all goes well you will have an awesome new background.